# How to fix Spring Boot Postgres error: syntax error at or near: ")" Position: 209

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, microservices

I've got some trouble attempting to rebuild connection with Postgres server using Spring Boot (in Eclipse environment). Case-relevant entities look like:

1 - Specialization - web application I'm working provides with online registration for college athlete courses, so `Specialization` means gymnastics or sports any student can apply for upon his/her pleasure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Specializations")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
public class Specialization {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "specialization_id_sequence", sequenceName = "specialization_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "specialization_id_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Short id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="health_category_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private HealthCategory category;

    @Column(name="photo_file_path")
    private String photoFilePath; 

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "specialization", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List <Trainer> trainerList;


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "specialization", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List <Group> groupList;

    //some hashCode() and equals() stuff here  

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Specialization [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", min. approvable health category=" + 
                category.getId() + ", path=" + photoFilePath + "]"; 
    }
```

2 - HealthCategory - prerequisite health class to be confirmed formally for getting admission to specialization-related engagement (different specilializations may be featured by the same health category required)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Health_categories")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
public class HealthCategory {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "category_id_sequence", sequenceName = "category_id_sequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "category_id_sequence")
@Column(name = "id")
private Short id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name; 

@Column(name="state")
private Short state;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List <Specialization> specialization;   

@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@Column(name="last_update")
private Date last_update;   

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List <User> userList;   

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Health category [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", state=" + state + ", last update on=" + last_update + "]"; 
}
```

3 - Group - specialization-related group a student sign in to pass the course

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Groups")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
public class Group {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "groupIdSequence", sequenceName = "groupIdSequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "groupIdSequence")
@Column(name = "group_id")
private Long group_id;  

// eventual values: "open", "close"   
@Column(name="registration_status")
private String registrationStatus;

// admission quota    
@Column(name="target_size")
private Integer targetSize;

// real group size evaluation at the moment  
@Column(name="actual_size")
private Integer actualSize; 


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List <User> userList;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="group_specialization_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Specialization specialization;


@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(
    name="schedules",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="schedule_id", nullable = false) })     
private List<GroupSchedule> scheduleList;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupList")
private List<Trainer> trainerList;

@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
@JoinTable(
    name="locations",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", nullable = false) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="location_id", nullable = false) })
private List<Location> locationList;

@Column(name="description")
private String desciption;
```

4 - Trainer - an instructor concerned of holding lessons for respective groups of student who take specific course:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Trainers")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor 
public class Trainer {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "trainerIdSequence", sequenceName = "trainerIdSequence", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "trainerIdSequence")
@Column(name = "trainer_id")
private Short trainer_id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="second_name")
private String secondName;

@Column(name="last_name)")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="photo_file_path")
private String photoFilePath;   

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="specialization_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
private Specialization specialization;

@ManyToMany(cascade =  {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(
    name="groups",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "trainer_id", nullable = false) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="group_id", nullable = false) })
private List<Group> groupList;
```

Because of difficulties when running code with `Specialization` objects, `SpecializationService` to be posted here:

```
@Service
public class SpecializationService {

    @Autowired
    private SpecializationRepository specializationRepository;

    public SpecializationService(SpecializationRepository specializationRepository) {
        this.specializationRepository = specializationRepository;       
    }

    public void createSpecialization(Specialization specialization) {
        specializationRepository.save(specialization);
    }

    public List<Specialization> findALL() {
        return (List<Specialization>) specializationRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Specialization> getSpecializations() {
        List<Specialization> specializations = new ArrayList<>();
        specializationRepository.findAll().forEach(specializations::add);
        return specializations;     
    }
}
```

`SpecializationController` code:

```
@RestController
public class SpecializationController {

    @Autowired
    SpecializationService specializationService;

    @RequestMapping("/specialization")
    public List<Specialization> getSpecializations() {
        return specializationService.getSpecializations();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/specialization/create")
    public void createSpecialization(@RequestBody Specialization spec) {
        specializationService.createSpecialization(spec);
    }       
}
```

Additively, there is relevant sql `create table` stuff:

```
    CREATE SEQUENCE category_id_sequence;
    CREATE TABLE Health_Categories (
        id SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('category_id_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
        state SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        last_update TIMESTAMP 
    );

    -- Specialization --
    CREATE SEQUENCE specialization_id_sequence;  
    CREATE TABLE Specializations (
        id SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('specialization_id_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,  
        health_category_id SMALLINT REFERENCES health_categories (id),
        photo_file_path VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT specialization_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES health_categories (id)
    );
```

Once executing `@SpringBootApplication` class as follows:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DatabaseComponentsApplication {

@Autowired
private HealthCategoryService categoryService;

@Autowired
private SpecializationService specializationService;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DatabaseComponentsApplication.class, args);
}   

@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
private void testJpaMethods() {

    HealthCategory cat2 = new HealthCategory();
    Date date = new Date();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    cat2.setLast_update(ts);
    cat2.setName("Test2");
    cat2.setSpecialization(null);
    cat2.setState((short) 8);
    categoryService.createCategory(cat2);

    Specialization spec = new Specialization();
    spec.setCategory(cat2);
    spec.setName("Soccer");
    spec.setPhotoFilePath(null);

    specializationService.createSpecialization(spec);
    specializationService.getSpecializations().forEach(it -> System.out.println(it));       

    }
}
```

it complains due to wrongness I still can't figure out to manage:

```
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: error: syntax error at or near: ")"  Position: 209
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2505) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2241) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:310) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:368) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:158) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:108) ~[postgresql-42.2.9%20(1).jar:42.2.9]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.9.Final.jar:5.4.9.Final]
    ... 74 common frames omitted
```

Could you share your ideas what syntax issue causes that?

EDITED: `pom.xml` code as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>databaseComponents</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>databaseComponents</name>
    <description>DAO implementation draft </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/> 
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also, `application.properties` stuff:

```
spring.datasource.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/core_database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.main.web-application-type=none
```

Comment: Can you share database configuration file?

Comment: @Dhwanil Patel, do you mean `application.properties`, `pom.xml` or some other file to be added to code I posted earlier?

Comment: Wherever you define your database configuration. Both way possible, app.properties or pom.xml

Comment: Did you debug your code? If no then do that. Because it's sure that exception occurred because the query which created by system is not proper. So as per my suggestion run project on debugging mode place your code on try catch put debug on catch block and explore the cause section it give accurate place where the issue is. : )

Comment: Code extended with `application.properties` and `pom.xml`. Sure, I've tried to run debugging, it comes to some problems occurred when executing `specializationService.getSpecializations().forEach(it -> System.out.println(it));`. What a problem is it? I hardly can guess because there is my first experience with Postgres. Sorry, but this error statement doesn't convey any kind of catchy ideas what was going wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the postgres logs?  They will likely show the query that caused the error, which should give some hints.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any problem with calling `findAll()` method.

```
public List<Specialization> findAll() {
    return (List<Specialization>) specializationRepository.findAll();
}
```

Can you replace `getSpecializations()` method

```
specializationService.getSpecializations().forEach(it -> System.out.println(it));
```

with `findALL()` method

```
specializationService.findALL().forEach(it -> System.out.println(it));
```

and see if it works ?

Comment: You can write System.out.println as Consumer directly in forEach. Just call static method. Like: specializationService.findALL().forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: Thanks, Denis . But actually, I can't understand why @Haskell Steam Machine create findALL() and getSpecializations() methods at the same time.